# Plot csv file with readable timestamps?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I've made a 2-channel datalogger and want to plot the resulting csv in a "human friendly" way.
The csv file is like:

```
hh:mm,m,ch1 , ch2 ,--
15:24,0,61.5,66.0
15:25,1,61.1,66.0
15:26,2,60.0,65.0
15:27,3,58.5,63.0
15:29,4,57.7,62.0
15:30,5,57.2,62.0
15:31,6,55.6,60.0
  ...   ...
```

And the code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y1= []
y2 = []

with open('Documentos/valores2.csv','r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    last = ""
    ini = ""
    for row in lines:
        if len(row) != 4: continue
        if ini =="": ini = row[0]
        if   row[0] == last: 
            continue
        last = row[0]
        x.append(int(ini[:2])+(int(row[1])+int(ini[3:5]) ) /60)
        y1.append(float(row[2]))
        y2.append(float(row[3]))
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 6))
fig.suptitle(' Documentos/valores.csv\nde '+ini[:-1]+" a "+last[:-1], fontsize = 14)

ax.plot(x, y1, color="red", label="cantero 1")
ax.plot(x, y2, color="green", label="cantero 2")

plt.legend(loc="lower right", title="", frameon=False)
plt.xlabel('hora')
plt.show()
```

Resulting:
[image]

I would like to have hour "1" and "6" instead of hour "25" and "30" ... !

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have those abscissae (20, 25, 30, etc) that you cannot change, unless you want to break the order of measurements, so you need to change the way those numbers are *displayed*, and to do that you must use [`matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter).

While we are at it, I suggest to use also [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) from the same module, so that the hours are numbered like hours, and introduce also the minor ticks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MultipleLocator

# we take the hour, modulo 24, and we format starting with 00
formatter24 = FuncFormatter(lambda t,_:"%02.2d"%(t%24))

t = np.linspace(15.5, 38, 301)
y = 12+3*np.sin(6.28*t/20) + t

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, y)

# change the formatters
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter24)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter24)
# change the locators
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(6))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
# tailor the minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', labelsize=6, colors='gray')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Fine ! In my case,  little bit generalization:
    t = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], len(x))

Comment: @RodolfoLeibner NO! I've used `linspace` because I  didn't want to mess with real dates, you must use your `x` vector of times.

Comment: In this particular case, the x vector is linear yet.

Answer (score 0):

In a simpler way, we can format the vector x itself:

```
... ...
formatter24 = lambda x,n : "%.2f"%(x%24)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter24)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1/6))
ax.set_xlim(int(x[0]), 1+int(x[-1]))
... ...
```